# Add code to every canvas context method

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add some code to every method called on the canvas context. I am trying to do this so I can add each command to an array of commands. This is the code I would think works (but doesn't):

```
var canvas = Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'));
for(p in canvas){
    if(canvas.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        var original = canvas[p];
        canvas[p] = function(){

            //extra code to be run

            return original.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to me like it should work, but it doesn't. If I use this code in an example, I get a `NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9`

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J3tUD/2/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're suffering from is the fact that variables aren't block scoped.

When your function runs, it updates the context prototype so that each function calls the same function `original`, which is the last element owned by the original prototype.  In this case, that is `webkitGetImageDataHD`.

This means when you call `ctx.beginPath();` you really call `ctx.webkitGetImageDataHD();`.  This method expects 4 arguments and since it didn't get them it throws the DOM Exception 9.

Since JavaScript doesn't support block scope, you have to force a scope change using a function.  Modifying your example, we can create a new function where `original` is a fixed value:

```
var context = Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'));

function bind(context, p) {
    // context, p, and original never change.
    var original = context[p];
    context[p] = function(){
        console.log(p, arguments);
        return original.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}

// p changes with every iteration.
for(p in context){
    if(context.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        bind(context, p);
    }
}
```

Find a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/UG9gF/

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no block scope, and you have only one `original` variable containing the last enumerated function.

This solution won't change the context prototype (a [host object](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)!), but only the copies for `myContext`:

```
var myContext = someCanvas.getContext('2d');
var CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(myContext);
for (var p in CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype) (function(original, prop) {
    myContext[prop] = function() {
        // some extra code
        original.apply(myContext, arguments);
    };
})(CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype[p], p);
```

Comment: `this` would be appropriate.  Using `myContext` will make all rendering actions go to the same canvas rather than their own.

Comment: Yes, I've already commented that out. I first missed that his `canvas` variable in fact is the prototype of all canvases